# Cannot use \upgreek due to some Euler font problem - TeXLive

Tags: fonts, pdftex, euler

I made recently a switch to Manjaro Linux and am struggling with the `\upgreek` package for some days now. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}

$\uppi$

\end{document}
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
: pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file eurm10): Font eurm10 at 600 not found []
```

I'm sure there is some easy solution to my problem, but since I do not really understand the font mapping and stuff going on, I have no clue what to do :/

I appreciate every helpful comment!

Comment: Your code compiles for me, **not** using Manjaro Linux

Comment: I used LMDE2 before and had no difficulties. With Manjaro I did the usual installation procedure: texlive-most and texlive-lang..

Answer (score 1):

Though I have no clue why I have to do it explicitly, but adding

```
\usepackage{euler}
```

to the preamble solved it! The document compiles now and displays upgreek letters correctly.